# Are lightning component visibility filters deployable? Where can I find them in metadata?

Tags: metadata-api, visibility, lightning-components

I have some custom lightning components on the layout. These components have some visibility filters. I need to add and remove some filters. It is easy to do it in UI in page layout settings, but is there any way to find such filters in metadata to have ability to retrieve and deploy?

Comment: why you don't deploy the lightning page itself together with the component? It will retain the filters

Comment: @sanketkumar I can, but I was asking about the place in metadata, cause I didn’t know where it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be found in flexiPages folder in metadata. And inside the flexiPage you can see it:

```
<flexiPageRegions>
    <componentInstances>
        <componentName>cmpYourLightningComponent</componentName>
        <visibilityRule>
            <booleanFilter>1 OR 2 OR 3</booleanFilter>
            <criteria>
                <leftValue>{!$User.Profile.Name}</leftValue>
                <operator>CONTAINS</operator>
                <rightValue>Admin</rightValue>
            </criteria>
            <criteria>
                <leftValue>{!$User.Profile.Name}</leftValue>
                <operator>CONTAINS</operator>
                <rightValue>Reps</rightValue>
            </criteria>
            <criteria>
                <leftValue>{!$User.Profile.Name}</leftValue>
                <operator>CONTAINS</operator>
                <rightValue>Ops</rightValue>
            </criteria>
        </visibilityRule>
    </componentInstances>
<flexiPageRegions>
```